# Share a resource between mocha tests

Tags: mocha.js

How do I share a resource, such as a connection, between mocha tests?

`cookies.test.js`:

```
describe('Cookies', function() {
  it('setCookie()', function() {
    connection.setCookie('foo', 'foo-content')
    connection.cookies['foo'].should.equal('foo-content')
  }
}
```

`shutdown.test.js`:

```
describe('Connection', function() {
  it('shutdown()', function() {
    connection.shutdown()
    connection.connected.should.be.false()
  }
}
```

How could `connection` itself be shared across these two files, while being initialised only once?
In reality there are hundreds of tests and that is why sharing it would be essential.

Answer (score 2):

Your `connection` object carries state. Sharing state between tests is considered to be a bad practice.

If you *must* share it for some overriding reason, Mocha won't help you with this. What you can do is create a module:

```
var connection = new Connection(...);

module.exports = connection;
```

And then in each test get your connection from the module. If the module is named `TestCollection` your test files should contain:

```
var connection = require('TestConnection');
```

Since modules are loaded only once, all your test files will get the same connection.

Comment: Thanks. Already doing this, however as it's asynchronous, still need to handle the `'connected'` event in each test. What I'm really looking for is a `before()` thats "result" is saved, is that possible?